# In django-cms Why preview button of page not able to load web page?

Tags: python, django-cms

I have started to learn django-cms recently and got one project from one of my friends.

I have created two pages in django-cms.

When I click on preview(eye-icon) from pages, my second page preview does not show & instead showing below error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/event-page/?edit&language=en
Raised by:  aldryn_newsblog.views.ArticleDetail

No News / Blog Article found matching the query, tried languages: en

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I tried to find solution online but not able to find any.

It will be great help if someone can suggest me solution.